# I cannot add custom words to my Voice Control Vocabulary

Tags: macos, catalina, voice-dictation, voice-control

I have downloaded Apple Catalina, and I have in enabled Voice control, but the vocabulary option is greyed out. I have the English(Australian) language chosen.

How do I enable the vocabulary options so that I can add and modify new words?